# Verb mood after “pouvoir”

Tags: grammaire, verbes

This is a subject that I find a bit confusing.

Lets say I want to say: "Could you give me a cake?"
Would the correct translation be:

> Pourriez-vous me **donne** un gâteau?

or

> Pourriez-vous me **donner** un gâteau?

I read the conjugation of donner [here](http://french.about.com/od/verb_conjugations/a/donner.htm), and concluded that the correct form for present 1st person singular would be "donne", but it seems that most sentences including **give me** just use the infinitive: donner.

Is anyone able to explain which one is correct and why? And hence would this be correct?:

> Pourriez-vous **lui donner** un gâteau (could you **give him** a cake)

**Edit** changed 'se' to 'lui'

Comment: About the title edit: This question is only useful to people that look up “pouvoir”. The verb that follows is not interesting, it could be “vendre”, “acheter”, “cuisiner”, it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pourriez-vous me donner un gâteau?

Always infinitive with the translation of the modal can.

Can you... Could you.. Will you...
All give infinitive when you translate in French.

Comment: so would the sentence at the bottom be correct?

Comment: Et : Pourriez-vous *lui* donner...

Comment: Oh thank you, I will edit it now, I will mark correct in 9 minutes when I am able to again!

Comment: A good way to remember that it has to be infinitive is by translating it in your head "able". So for "Pourriez-vous me donner..." you would have "are you able **to give**..." Just a little tip.

Answer (score 5):

A verb form that varies depending on the person always has a subject indicating the person. A verb that is a complement of another verb lacks a subject and can only be in an impersonal mood: infinitive or participle.

For example, in a sentence like “*Pourriez-vous me **donner** un gâteau?*”, there are two verbs: *pourriez* and *donner*. The verb *pourriez* is the main verb of the sentence; it is in the conditional mood and its subject is *vous*. The verb *donner* is a complement of *pourriez*; it has no grammatical subject, and it is in the infinitive mood.

Apart from the passive voice and from past tenses, most of the time, when a verb is a complement of another verb, the complement is an infinitive. The alternative is that the complement is a full subordinate clause with a subject and a verb in a personal mood (indicative, subjunctive or conditional). Usually, when the semantic subject of the main verb and the complement verb are the same, we use an infinitive, and not a full subordinate clause.

Answer (score 2):

To the first question, you must use

> Pourriez-vous me donn**er** un gâteau ? *(infinitive form)*

And for the last

> Pourriez-vous **lui** donner un gâteau ? *(personal pronoun, 3rd person)*

Your *se* was an error, because you used the reflexive form, which is not the case here (**You** give **him** a cake)

I don't know what exactly is unclear to you, could you precise ?

Comment: +1 for the clear answer, sorry I could not accept as you were just 2nd! Thank you very much though I appreciate your help :)